# Не работает проверка if до словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, if

Когда применяю данную проверку здесь - она не работает.

```
first, second, operation = float(input()), float(input()), input()

Сomputation = {
    "+": first + second,
    "-": first - second,
    "*": first * second,
    "/": first / second,
    "mod": first % second,
    "pow": first ** second,
    "div": first // second
}

Status = False
for keys in Сomputation.keys():
    if operation == keys:
       Status = True
       if (second == 0 or first == 0) and (operation == "/" or operation == "div" or operation == "mod"):
           print("Division by 0!")
       else:
            print(Сomputation[keys])

if Status != True:
    print("Do not work")
```

Но когда пишу так, то проверка срабатывает корректно.

```
first, second, operation = float(input()), float(input()), input()
if (second == 0 or first == 0) and (operation == "/" or operation == "div" or operation == "mod"):
    print("Division by 0!")
    exit(0)

Сomputation = {
    "+": first + second,
    "-": first - second,
    "*": first * second,
    "/": first / second,
    "mod": first % second,
    "pow": first ** second,
    "div": first // second
}

Status = False
for keys in Сomputation.keys():
    if operation == keys:
       Status = True
       print(Сomputation[keys])

if Status != True:
    print("Do not work")
```

Спросив у знакомого, более опытного человека, он объяснил это тем, что в словаре выполняется ранее, чем проходит проверка. Но, саму то инструкцию я даю после словаря. Так-же буду видеть код, который Вы считаете альтернативой этому.

Comment: У вас уже при хаполнении словаря все действия выполняются, до проверки дело не доходит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас значения словаря уже выполнились.

Чтобы можно было выполнять код из значения словаря, его нужно сделать вызываемым, например, через лямбды

Пример:

```
first, second, operation = float(input()), float(input()), input()

# <<<<<<<<<<<<
Сomputation = {
    "+": lambda first, second: first + second,
    "-": lambda first, second: first - second,
    "*": lambda first, second: first * second,
    "/": lambda first, second: first / second,
    "mod": lambda first, second: first % second,
    "pow": lambda first, second: first ** second,
    "div": lambda first, second: first // second
}
# <<<<<<<<<<<<

Status = False
for keys in Сomputation.keys():
    if operation == keys:
       Status = True
       if (second == 0 or first == 0) and operation in ("/", "div", "mod"):
           print("Division by 0!")
       else:
            print(Сomputation[keys](first, second))  # <<<<<<<<<<<<

if Status != True:
    print("Do not work")
```

---

**PS.**

Проверку `operation == "/" or operation == "div" or operation == "mod"` можно упросить, если значение поместить, например, в кортеж и проверить наличие `operation` в нем, т.е.:

```
operation in ("/", "div", "mod")
```

---

**PPS.**

Код можно упростить:

```
first, second, operation = float(input()), float(input()), input()

# Сразу проверяем допустимость операции
if (second == 0 or first == 0) and operation in ("/", "div", "mod"):
    print("Division by 0!")
    exit()

Сomputation = {
    "+": lambda first, second: first + second,
    "-": lambda first, second: first - second,
    "*": lambda first, second: first * second,
    "/": lambda first, second: first / second,
    "mod": lambda first, second: first % second,
    "pow": lambda first, second: first ** second,
    "div": lambda first, second: first // second
}

# Если операции нет в словаре
if operation not in Сomputation:
    print("Do not work")
    exit()

# Достаем лямбду по операции и выполняем ее
print(Сomputation[operation](first, second))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку. Всё работает.

Comment: @РоманЯровой, посмотрите еще в **PPS** :)

Comment: да-да, он мне особенно понравился) Спасибо большое